# A warning didn't appears after compiled, why it warns me?

Tags: swift, properties, enumeration

I create an enumeration contains all months of the year. The computed value of the enumeration returns the university semesters based on the input month

```
enum Month{
    case January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December


var schoolSemester: String {
            switch self {
        case .April, .September, .October, .November, .December:
            return "Autumn"
        case .January, .February, .March, .April, .May:
            return "Sping" // Here comes the warning
       default:
            return "Not in the school year"
        }
    }
}

var whichSemester = Month.February
print(whichSemester.schoolSemester)//even though the warning says this will never be executed, but it was executed!
```

**Question1**: Why Xcode keeps telling me that the second case will never be executed (which is wrong! I did execute the case by assign the February to the Month)
[image]

**Question 2**: Is calculated property a Lazy property?

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: You listed the case `.April` *twice* ...

Comment: A lazy property is not the same as a computed property. A computed property is evaluated every time you access it – a lazy property is evaluated only on the first time you access it, and then stored.

Comment: @originaluser2 How about the second time I access a lazy property? will it be renewed and stored again?

Comment: @SLN No, you'll be accessing the stored version. A lazy property is only designed to be evaluated once – although you can write back to it yourself.

Comment: You should not put two unrelated problems into the same question ...

Comment: @MartinR Good suggestion, thanks

Comment: @originaluser2 The lazy property sounds like a constant, once been evaluated it then settles down

Comment: @SLN It's not a constant, you can still write back it like a normal read-write property. Maybe the [Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) can explain it better than me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler issues a warning because you apparently mistyped 
`.August` as `.April` in the first case, so that `.April` occurs in
both cases.

The compiler could not notice that you omitted `.August` because you used
a default case. It is therefore better to list all possible enumeration
values explicitly instead:

```
var schoolSemester: String {
    switch self {
    case .April, .September, .October, .November, .December:
        return "Autumn"
    case .January, .February, .March, .April, .May:
        return "Spring"
    case .June, .July:
        return "Not in the school year"
    }
```

Now the compiler issues both a warning and an *error*

```
warning: case will never be executed
        case .January, .February, .March, .April, .May:
error: switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause
```

and the code does *not compile.*  It forces you to check all cases
again, and you'll quickly notice that `.August` is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the code and detailed interpretation. Nice explanation and extension

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you have .April on the first case and on the second case. That's the reason the second case will never be executed.

Comment: Cool! it works after .April is removed from the first case. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

.April is listed for two different cases, so the statement will never execute the second case containing April. Simply remove April from one of the cases and it'll work!

Comment: Yes! after remove a .April from one of the list, there is no more warning